# SSH Command to save output in specific directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, compiler-flags

I have an executable file in a directory, when I run that file (using ./file) I get an output file (.out), which are saved on the same directory of the executable file. I want this output to be saved in a subdirectory of the mentioned directory. What command/flag should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- **IF** you redirect the output to file `out` yourself:

  ```
  cd directory || exit
  ./file >.out
  ```

  then you can do:

  ```
  cd directory || exit
  ./file >subdir/.out
  ```
- **IF** the `file` executable creates its own `.out` file:

  ```
  cd directory || exit
  ./file
  ```

  the .out file is created by the executable, and you cannot change it (ex. it is not a script), move the file yourself:

  ```
  cd directory || exit
  ./file && mv .out subdir
  ```

You could wrap this into a script, call it myfile:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  cd directory || exit
  ./file
  mv .out subdir/.out
```

Comment: Ty! You solved my question!